# As x appraoches 0, make z approach 100

Tags: java, numbers

I want to make a method that will return me a value (let's call it "z"). Its value is dictated by one other value(let's call this "y"). Basically what I want is to make it so that the following conditions are met:

- As x approaches 0, z approaches 100.
- As x approaches infinity, z approaches 0.

So far I have this as my code:

```
if(x == 0){
       z = 100;
} else if(x1 > 0){
       //Code for what happens otherwise.
}
else if(x1 < 0){
       z = 100;
}
```

I'm really stuck on what to do otherwise. If anybody could lend their math/java expertise, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Could you just flip the sign and use that instead of 0-infinity?

Comment: The answer depends on the speed at which you would like `z` to approach zero: for example, `100 / (x+1)` would do the trick - it will be 100 when `x` is zero, and go down to zero as `x` goes up, but it's going to become small pretty fast, so I doubt that this would be the right solution.

Comment: And from which direction are you wanting them to approach their respective values?

Comment: Let's say x starts at any positive number. I want as x decreases (by a factor of let's say 1) then the number z will change accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

```
z = 100.0 / (1 + x)
```

Remember to declare `x` and `z` as `double`s if you want non-integer values.

Comment: This fits OP's bill, but it goes down rather fast, reaching `1` when `x` is at 99, and it's only downhill from there.

Comment: So basically the bigger number I replace 1 with will change how fast it goes?

Comment: I just noticed that it doesn't account for when x > 99. I don't think I can use this

Comment: It does handle `x > 99`, unless for some reason you need integers only. If so, your choice gets a lot more complicated.

Comment: If you want to adjust how fast it goes, replacing `1` with some other number won't work. You could instead use `100.0 / (1 + x * some_scale_factor)`, though there's a limit to what that can do to the shape of the curve.